# R: power.t.test: How to estimate required sampling size for UNKNOWN population variance?

Tags: r, variance

I am trying to use the following code in R to estimate the required sampling size to reach certain power and significant level for UNKNOWN population variance:

```
power.t.test(delta = 5, sd=sigma, sig.level=0.05, power = .80, type="one.sample", alternative = "one.sided")
```

In the code above, `sigma` is a predefined value. Because the population variance is UNKNOWN, I think I need to use `sd = NULL` instead of `sd=sigma`. However, when it is `sd = NULL`, I got the error message:

```
Error in power.t.test(delta = 5, sd = NULL, sig.level = 0.05, power = 0.8,  
:exactly one of 'n', 'delta', 'sd', 'power', and 'sig.level' must be NULL
```

So can I ask how to properly set the arguments?

Comment: Population variance should be unknown, that is why you are using `t.test`, put `sd` equal to your sample standard deviation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics and not really a specific programming question. Perhaps it's better to ask this on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Hi Soheil, I am trying to estimate how many samples I need before I conducting the analysis. That is to say, I have no sample data yet and thus I do not know the "sample standard deviation".

Comment: You have two unknown arguments: `n` and `sd`, but the function can only accept one unknown parameter. For a fixed sample size `n` you can identify the unknown population sd that enables you to detect a difference between the two populations with the given power.

Comment: @ekstroem, I see. Thank you I got it.
I also asked questions here and I got the answer.
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184121/r-power-t-test-how-to-estimate-required-sampling-size-for-unknown-population-v